# SQL Query to get Last binary left or right position

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have binary tree presented in a table in a SQL Server 2014 database:

```
UserID ParentUserID Position 
------------------------------
1      null         null     <-- ROOT
2      1            Left
3      1            Right    <-- Last right for ID=1 (query should return 3)
4      2            Left
5      4            Left
6      2            Left
7      6            Left     <-- Last left for ID=1 (query should return 6)
```

Here is graphic representation:

[image]

I need to write 2 queries. The red lines of the diagram above show what nodes I need to retrieve;

1. Last left leg id.
2. Last right leg id

How can I achieve my goal... should I use recursive query?

Could you please provide an example of queries I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recurse down the left or right hand side with a recursive common-table expression (CTE.)  Using `select top 1 * ... order by depth` you can find the deepest node:

```
; with  left_hand_recurse as
        (
        select  UserID
        ,       ParentUserID
        ,       1 as depth
        from    Table1 where ParentUserID is null
        union all
        select  child.UserID
        ,       child.ParentUserID
        ,       parent.depth + 1
        from    left_hand_recurse parent
        join    Table1 child
        on      parent.UserID = child.ParentUserID
                and position = 'Left'
        )
select  top 1 *
from    left_hand_recurse
order by
        depth desc
;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3c22/1/0)

P.S. Your example data makes both 6 and 4 a left parent of 2.  I assume that 6 is the left parent of 5.

Comment: Great ! Exactly what was I looking for. I thought about CTE and was trying to use 'with' but you are much faster. Thanks a lot!